# defineAsyncComponent with vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I use defineAsyncComponent to import my component with vue3 like this

```
const PieChart = defineAsyncComponent({
    loader: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "PieChart" */"@/Components/Chart/PieChart.vue"),
});
```

Now I have component that have specific exports like this

```
import { Carousel, Pagination, Slide } from "vue3-carousel";
```

How can I import them by using defineAsyncComponent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 named imports in defineAsyncComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68664491/es6-named-imports-in-defineasynccomponent)